# What is Git fast-forwarding?

Tags: git

Is it OK to assume that fast-forward means all commits are replayed on the target branch and the `HEAD` is set to the last commit on that branch?

Comment: See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging which explains this with an example and diagrams

Answer (score 288, accepted):

When you try to merge one commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward, because there isn't any divergent work to merge together—this is called a `fast-forward`.

For more: *[3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)*

In another way,

If *master* has not diverged, instead of creating a new commit, Git will just point the master to the latest commit of the feature branch. This is a `fast forward`.

There won't be any `merge commit` in fast-forwarding merge.

Comment: Does it mean "let the local HEAD be the remote HEAD"?

Comment: @Victor that's how I would intepret it as well. Meaning you can only commit if your local master is up to date with the remote master.

Answer (score 97):

In Git, to "fast forward" means to update the `HEAD` pointer in such a way that its new value is a direct descendant of the prior value. In other words, the prior value is a parent, or grandparent, or grandgrandparent, ...

Fast forwarding is not possible when the new `HEAD` is in a diverged state relative to the stream you want to integrate. For instance, you are on `master` and have local commits, and `git fetch` has brought new upstream commits into `origin/master`. The branch now diverges from its upstream and cannot be fast forwarded: your `master` `HEAD` commit is not an ancestor of `origin/master` `HEAD`. To simply reset `master` to the value of `origin/master` would discard your local commits. The situation requires a rebase or merge.

If your local `master` has no changes, then it can be fast-forwarded: simply updated to point to the same commit as the latest`origin/master`. Usually, no special steps are needed to do fast-forwarding; it is done by `merge` or `rebase` in the situation when there are no local commits.

> *Is it ok to assume that fast-forward means all commits are replayed on the target branch and the HEAD is set to the last commit on that branch?*

No, that is called *rebasing*, of which fast-forwarding is a special case when there are no commits to be replayed (and the target branch has new commits, and the history of the target branch has not been rewritten, so that all the commits on the target branch have the current one as their ancestor.)

Comment: heads up for the rebase explanation!

Answer (score 13):

Imagine there is a branch

`Master : A---> B --->`

There are two commits on it, A and B
There is another feature branch, from B, it has the following commit History

`Feature : C--->D---->E`

So the present it looks like this

```
`A--->B`
     `C--->D--->E `
```

So when you want to merge it, you can do it by fast forward merge by moving the head from B to E and incorporating the feature branch in the main branch and it looks like this

`A--->B--->C--->D--->E` with the header at E.

This example by Atlassian is so good:
[image: Atlassian example]

[Atlassian Example](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge)

But as Mentioned in the example, this is only possible when the branches have not diverged, in which case the traditional merge or --no-ff works.

[Another Good Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ueMx5hro8&ab_channel=CameronMcKenzie)