# What is a fast-forwarding push in Git?

Tags: git

From the Git [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

> By default, the configuration flag receive.denyNonFastForwards is
> enabled in shared repositories, so that you cannot force a non
> fast-forwarding push into it.

I know about the `git push` command, but what is *fast-forwarding* push?

Comment: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684352/what-does-git-push-non-fast-forward-updates-were-rejected-mean)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \`git merge\` and \`git merge --no-ff\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)

Comment: Canonical: *[What is Git fast-forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673869/what-is-git-fast-forwarding)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, this means that you won't be rewriting commit history that already exists on your Git server (the already-pushed stuff).

If this history changes it could be a problem for others who have already pulled and worked off that history.

A manual way to determine if you are pushing "fast forward" is to look at what ref you have for your downloaded copy of your branches remote (let's say master):

```
git rev-parse origin/master # Returns SHA-1 hash value
```

Then, download the content from your remote server and check again:

```
git fetch
git rev-parse origin/master # Returns SHA-1 hash value
```

If the return result of those those two *rev-parse* commands are equal your push will be fast-forward.

***But...* **all that work really isn't necessary.** Just simply pull before you push and you will be good.

```
git pull origin master

# Resolve any conflicts
git push origin master
```

Comment: You meant: "pull before your push" (last sentence before last example).