# merge one local branch into another local branch

Tags: git, merge

I have multiple branches which are branched off the master (each in a separate subdirectory).

- Branch1: new development, not yet completely finished
- Branch2: hotfix for a problem, but still under test
- Branch3: mess around branch, which I will not restore

Before testing of the hotfix is finished I would like to have the code already available in Branch1, so I can continue developing with the fix in place.
(But since my experience with git is not that much I first started to play around with merge in a 3rd branch, especially created to mess around in, before I mess up either Branch1 or Branch2)

In my 3rd branch I first tried the following:

```
git merge feature/Branch1
```

but this gave the following error:

```
fatal: 'feature/Branch1' does not point to a commit
```

I next did a commit -a in my Branch1 and tried again, but it keeps giving the same error.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to merge the code from - in this case - Branch1 with Branch3?

Comment: This question is needlessly complex. It should be clearer which branch has the code and which branch we want that code to be merged in.

Answer (score 528, accepted):

First, checkout to your Branch3:

```
git checkout Branch3
```

Then merge the Branch1:

```
git merge Branch1
```

And if you want the updated commits of Branch1 on Branch2, you are probaly looking for [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

```
git checkout Branch2
git rebase Branch1
```

This will update your Branch2 with the latest updates of Branch1.

Comment: (I want the updates of Branch2 to Branch1 ;-) )
Branch2 does see Branch1, but not the other way around when I do a git branch -a in both branches.
Hence I cannot do a rebase to Branch2 in Branch1: 
    git rebase Branch2
--> fatal: Needed a single revision

Comment: When I do the rebase as git rebase origin/Branch2 it still gives that error message + invalid upstream origin/Branch2

Comment: So the above is merging all the commit of Branch1 into Branch3 or vice versa?
Master -> git branch Dev (while on Dev -> git branch Dev1). I made changes to Dev1 and would like to merge with Dev.

Comment: @Si8 this will add only the commits from Branch1 to Branch3. Branch1 will be kept as is.

Comment: Thank you so if I am currently in Dev branch and I do a merge of Dev1, it will merge Dev1 to Dev, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. I recommend trying it. If something breaks, you can go back. That is the purpose of a VCS.

Comment: Rebasing is like the force version of merge. Overwriting..

Answer (score 169):

```
 git checkout [branchYouWantToReceiveBranch] //checkout branch to receive branch
 git merge [branchYouWantToMergeIntoBranch]
```

Comment: Simple and should-be-the-accepted answer to me!

Comment: Agree, the best answer for me too, easy to understand.

Comment: Agree, thx a lot it helped me too

Comment: "branch you want to merge into" is ambiguous - it could mean "other branch you're going into" or "branch you want to go into this one". "branch you want to receive" is also ambiguous. It could mean "branch you want to receive into this one" or "branch you want to receive (in the sense of accept) the merge branch". It's not clear which way round this is.

Answer (score 119):

You can use these commands:

```
git checkout <the branch you want to merge into>

git merge <the branch you want contents from>
```

Comment: This is the fourth answer saying the exact same thing. Am I missing something, or why does this have 43 upvotes?

Comment: @phil294 this guy says the same thing better.

Comment: the readability is strong with this one

Comment: My preferred answer. It's more readable

Answer (score 62):

To merge one branch into another, such as merging "feature_x" branch into "master"* branch:

`git checkout master`

`git merge feature_x`

* Note that the original branch name is now commonly `main` instead of `master`.  Choose the correct name based on your situation.

*This page is the first result for several search engines when looking for "git merge one branch into another".  However, the original question is more specific and special case than the title would suggest.

It is also more complex than both the subject and the search expression.  As such, this is a minimal but explanatory answer for the benefit of most visitors.*

Answer (score 19):

Just in case you arrived here because you copied a branch name from Github, note that a remote branch is not automatically also a local branch, so a merge will not work and give the "not something we can merge" error.

In that case, you have two options:

```
git checkout [branchYouWantToMergeInto]
git merge origin/[branchYouWantToMerge]
```

or

```
# this creates a local branch
git checkout [branchYouWantToMerge]

git checkout [branchYouWantToMergeInto]
git merge [branchYouWantToMerge]
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more long winded approach, but it works none-the-less:

In branch 3:

```
git fetch origin Branch1
git merge --no-ff origin/Branch1
```

*At this point merge conflicts may occur, save all changes made to files containing merge conflicts*

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Merge"
git push
```

DONE

Answer (score 1):

Safer way, as of git 2.23.0

`git switch Branch3`

- to switch from current to *Branch3*

`git merge Branch1`

- to merge branch *Branch1* int current branch

(optionally) to update commits of one branch to another

```bash
git switch Branch2
git rebase Branch1
```

---

Why use `switch` branches instead of `checkout`:

- saver way to switch and merge branches by using dedicated commands to switch branches instead of multipurpose `checkout`.
- `Checkout` command was split into (replaced by) the `switch` and `restore` commands because it was confusing and easy to make mistake.
- Here is project git [commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d787d311dbd7a4104a9dde23b90ae24528a15cf9) that introduced the split into `switch` and `restore` command with explanation.
- Here is explanation from git team:

> "git checkout" doing too many things is a source of confusion for many
> users (and it even bites old timers sometimes). To remedy that, the
> command will be split into two new ones: switch and restore. The good
> old "git checkout" command is still here and will be until all (or most
> of users) are sick of it.

---

The extra info:

- might come in handy when you don't want to make two branches into single branch
- e.g. `mess-around-branch` and `feature` has to have their own histories.
  or your `dev` branch has to include every single "step" but `master` should only includes cumulative commit of all commits made to `dev` branch.

Git by default uses "[fast-forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673869/what-is-git-fast-forwarding)", humanly understandable meaning, it will merge branches into single branch in history if possible (moving pointer to the latest commit, not merge commit) [Git Branching...](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

it will merge this

```bash
| * changed targetSdk 32 to 33
| * code cleaning
|/
* First commit
```

into this

```bash
* changed targetSdk 32 to 33
* code cleaning
* First commit
```

if you need branch histories tell git not to use --no-ff

`git merge --no-ff Branch1`

and lets you commit changes created by merge manually

- merge but keeps both branches in log

```bash
*   code cleaning, sdk 33
|\
| * changed targetSdk 32 to 33
| * code cleaning
|/
* First commit
```

---