# Merge the changes from one Git branch (One File) to another locally

Tags: linux, git, github

I am new to Git, Currently I have two local Git branches with the same files (lets say BranchA and BranchB). I did one check-in/commit in BranchA (file xyz.c) long back.

Now i am working on BranchB and want to merge those check-in changes from BranchA to BranchB (merging two local branch file) without being change anything in Master branch.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206196/merge-one-local-branch-into-another-local-branch

Comment: @wookiekim Looks applicable, did you flag as duplicate?

Comment: oops, no. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the working tree is clean.
Then, git marge BranchA