# How do I syncronize my outdated (remote) dev branch with my master branch?

Tags: git, github

I am using github and have only two branches, one for development (*dev*) and one *master*. I recently created the dev branch from master, but have since made a few pushes to (remote) master, and have a few unstaged changes in (local) master, so the remote *dev* branch is behind a few commits. (And the local *dev* branch is still non-existent, AFAICT.)

I suppose the pictorial diagram would be something like this:

```
        c  (remote) branch 'dev' 
       /         
  a---b---d---e--*  (remote) branch 'master' (refers to commit 'e')
                     (local) branch 'master' (refers to unstaged changes '*') 
                               ^
                               |
                              HEAD (refers to branch 'master')
```

**Question:**

**How do I synchronize my outdated (remote) *dev* branch with my *master* branch?**
(And getting the unstaged changes into the (remote) *dev* branch.)

---

I understand there are 2 options to do this:

1. using the github web interface
2. using git from command line.

So it would be great to understand how to do both.

I've read dozens of SO answers (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512549/how-to-fast-forward-a-branch-to-head), however it seem that every answer is different and I'm not able to get this straight in my head. I think the problem is that when I'm using command line, I'm doing something on a local clone, rather than on the remote, unlike on the web interface.

BTW, the web interface has two `Pull Request` buttons, one for each branch.
(Which one is the right one to use, in my case?)

[image]
[image]

---

My current status is:

```sh
## I started this with:
## git clone https://github.com/nobody/repo.git
## I then edited, pushed some files and created 'dev' branch via GH web.
## Finally I edited some more files, so now I have:

$ git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   CHANGELOG.md
        modified:   README.md

$ git branch -a

* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
```

**PS.** *For some reason, when Googling my question, I only get results for "syncing a fork", which clearly is not the same thing as what I am asking about here.*

Comment: The SO auto-suggested link does not address my question.

Answer (score 2):

> I think the problem is that when I'm using command line, I'm doing something on a local clone, rather than on the remote, unlike on the web interface.

That's correct.

It's important to remember that Git is a *distributed* version control system, and as such—and/or perhaps through socialist impulses<sup>1</sup>—Git doesn't believe<sup>1</sup> that any one Git repository is superior to any other Git repository.  In particular, why should the Git on GitHub with a repository with a `dev` and a `master` be any better than *your* Git on *your* machine working with a repository with a `master`?

Note that if you made your GitHub repository by using the "fork a repository" button on the GitHub web interface, your GitHub repository is itself a clone of a *third* repository.  The GitHub web interface "pull request" buttons are meant for delivering a request (via email and/or web) to whoever maintains this *third* repository, to take commits out of your GitHub repository.  This all gets very confusing, and it might help to name each repository.<sup>2</sup>  Let's name your own repository Fred, and call the one on GitHub Gertie.

GitHub tries to hide a lot of complexity, but in my opinion, this just makes everything even more confusing.  Ignore all the webby buttons, at least at first.

The next key is to realize that while each separate repository has its own *names*—Fred has Fred's `master` and Gertie has Gertie's `master`—they all share the actual *commits*, or at least, those commits that they have.  Git identifies each commit by a unique *hash ID*—these look like `0afbf6caa5b16dcfa3074982e5b48e27d452dbbb`, though you can shorten them to something less scary as long as it's still unique.<sup>3</sup>  If some particular commit's hash ID is `0afbf6c...`, you either have the thing with that ID in your repository, in which case you have the commit too, or you don't.

Meanwhile, these names—Fred's `master` and Gertie's `master`—serve to identify one particular hash ID.  If both Fred and Gertie have the commit, they *can* both have their `master` identify that hash ID.  If one of the two *doesn't* have the commit, though, they can't have the name point to that commit.  A repository must *have* the commit in order for the name to point to it (store its ID)!

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that.

<sup>2</sup>As long as you don't name them all Bruce.  [Or is that as long as you *do* name them all Bruce?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyVX3uJpqxc&t=9s)

<sup>3</sup>The problem is, how do you know how short you can go?  Git has its own internal code to figure that out, but that doesn't help us poor humans.

---

#### Transferring commits

There are two operations that transfer commits (and all the other objects that go with them) *from* one Git repository to another.  These are `git fetch` and `git push`.  They're actually pretty similar; they're just named after the *direction of transfer*, as seen from whichever Git it is that starts the transferring.  You `git fetch` commits *from* them *to* you, and you `git push` commits from you to them.

When you're doing this transferring, there are two parts to the job:

- Identify which commits to transfer (by their big ugly hash IDs).
- Set some *name*(s) on the end that *gets* commits, so as to *remember* the big ugly hash IDs.

This second step is where things are not symmetric.

In either case, though, you start by running `git fetch` or `git push`.  This tells your Git (Fred) to call up the other Git (Gertie).  Your Git, Fred, then asks Gertie what she has, or offers to send things to Gertie.  They exchange information about the commit hash IDs and figure out who's missing what, and then send the objects.  This gets the appropriate commits—and with them, any associated stuff like file names and contents—into Fred or into Gertie as needed.

Finally, whoever is sending also sends a *name*.  So if you're doing `git push`, you have Fred send Gertie a *name*, like `dev` or `master`, as part of a request: *Please set your `dev` or your `master` to this hash ID.*  It's up to Gertie, following rules set up by GitHub, to decide whether to *allow* this operation.  If she says no, you can try using a `git push --force`, which changes this from "polite request" to "command", but Gertie **can** *still* say no.

In the `fetch` direction, things are different.  Gertie sends Fred all her commits (that Fred doesn't have yet), along with *all* of her branch names.  Fred then takes her names—her `dev` and her `master`—and sets *his* `origin/dev` and `origin/master`.  That way, Fred does not disturb Fred's `dev` (if there is one), nor touch Fred's `master`.  And that's what these *remote-tracking* names, the ones that start with `origin/`, are about: they're just Fred's way of remembering what Fred saw on Gertie, the last time Fred talked to Gertie.

Because of that last point, if you have Fred call up Gertie with `git push`, and Fred offers Gertie some new commit(s) and asks her to set her `master` or her `dev` and she *accepts*, Fred will update Fred's `origin/master` or `origin/dev` as well.  That's an *opportunistic update:* Fred knows Gertie took the commits, so now Gertie's name must identify the specific commit Fred suggested.

#### Putting these two pieces together

> How do I synchronize my outdated (remote) dev branch with my master branch?

This means you want Gertie's `dev` to identify the commit labeled `e` in your diagram.

You can find anything that identifies commit `e` on your end—such as your name `master`, or your name `origin/master`, or your name `HEAD`, if all of those do in fact identify commit `e`.  (You can use `git rev-parse name` to find out what commit *`name`* identifies.  Or, run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`: remember this as Git Log with A DOG.  In fact, you probably should make an alias, `git adog`, that runs `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  For [Hysterical Raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html), [my alias for this is `git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html).)  Or, of course, you can use the raw hash ID.  Then you would *normally* run:

```
git push origin <thing-that-identifies-e>:dev
```

The name or hash ID on the left side of the colon is anything that identifies the commit you want to be sure Gertie has, and that you want to ask Gertie to set something to.  The name on the *right*—which must be a *name*—is the name you'll ask Gertie to *set*.  You want her to set her `dev`, so that's the name that must appear on the right.

When you do this, though, Gertie will see you asking her to move her `dev` from where it is now, identifying commit `c`, to identifying commit `e`.  She will refuse!  This particular movement will cause Gertie to drop commit `c` from her commit graph entirely, as she'll have *no* name for commit `c`.  That kind of operation—the one that loses commits—is a *non fast forward*, in Git terminology, and requires a "forced push".

Hence, what you'll really need is:

```
git push --force origin <thing-that-identifies-e>:dev
```

to turn the polite request ("do this thing that will lose commit `c` forever") into a command ("yes, do it even though it will lose `c`!").  Given the Git rules that GitHub uses by default, Gertie will then set her `dev` to point to commit `e`, and will lose commit `c` entirely.

If you want Gertie to *keep* commit `c`, despite having her move her `dev` so that her `dev` identifies commit `e`, have her set a *new* name to point to `c`, preferably before having her move her `dev`.  If not, well, removing commits is OK, as long as you mean it and know what you're doing.  Note that you currently have a name for `c`, but that name is `origin/dev`, and as soon as Gertie says "OK I've changed my `dev`", *your* Git—Fred—will update *your* `origin/dev` correspondingly, so you too will lose commit `c`.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>You'll actually keep it for at least another 30 days, through what Git calls *reflogs*.  Servers like GitHub usually don't keep reflogs, though, so they tend to shed unreachable commits immediately.

---

#### A side note: your `master` cannot point to anything unstaged

> ```
> (local) branch 'master' (refers to unstaged changes '*')
> ```

It's worth remembering that anything in your *work-tree* is not in Git at all, and anything you've *staged* but not yet *committed* is not saved anywhere permanent.  Your branch name `master` *must* point to a commit.  So your local `master` probably points not to `*`, but rather to `e`.

*Staging* a file really means copying it into what Git calls the *index*, overwriting the version that was there before.  The index, also called the *staging area* and sometimes the *cache*, is where you build up what `git commit` will write as the *next* commit.  Until it's actually committed, though, it's just "the index" and it does not have a commit hash ID.  It's changeable—commits are read-only and hence entirely unchangeable—so it has no ID and no branch name can hold the commit ID it doesn't have yet.

(The actual commit ID it gets, when you make the commit, depends on the *time* at which you make the commit, among other things.)

Comment: Wow! That was one great educational explanation of what's going on! Thank you for taking the time for this thorough explanation. However, although much more clear now, I still fail to see: (a) what I need to do to save what I've already got (the un-staged stuff), (b) what commands I need to do to sync `dev` to `master` so that I can start using *dev* instead of *master* to develop on? Perhaps it is easier to just delete *dev* and create a new one? But I wanted to avoid that. (c) How to ensure that the `dev` history remain continuous in the future.

Comment: Ah, I thought (based on your good graph drawing) that you were further along in some Git tutorial. :-) You should read up on the difference between the *work-tree* (where files are in their normal everyday form) and the *index* aka *staging area* (where Git has the files stored in special Git form, but you can replace them at any time). Running `git commit` turns the index into a new commit, freezing the stored special-Git-form files, so that overwriting the index copy doesn't lose the saved for-(mostly-unless-deleted)-ever committed version.

Comment: To create a branch named `dev` in your own local repository, there are two main Git commands: `git branch`, and `git checkout -b`. The details are a bit long for a comment, unfortunately. The key is that branch names are just pointers, pointing to existing commits.

Comment: Ultimately, if you have a commit—or a whole chain of commits—whose position in the graph is "wrong", you are forced to *copy* the commits to new ones. This is what `git rebase` really does. There are a bunch of side issues that are consequences of this, which make some argue that no one should ever rebase.

Comment: I can only agree with @torek. While this question is nicely formatted and well phrased I think **a lot** of your questions could be answered by simply doing a tutorial on git. Personally I can recommend the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). After reading that you will probably be able to answer questions on git to your colleagues. 